# SUM Column based on Calculation Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rdl

I have the following table:

```
------------------------------------
Delivered     Return       Remain
------------------------------------
3             3            0
3             0            3
4             2            2
------------------------------------
```

Let say, the header column is start on `Column A` and `Row 1`.
So I want to have the total of `Delivered` column. `=SUM(A2:A4)`. Now, I want to have another total of `Delivered` column with some condition. The condition is, only total if `A2 - B2` is not zero (0).

Does anyone have an idea for this?
Really Appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways. This should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A:A)<>(B:B))*(A:A))
```

If you have 2019 Excel or later you could do...

```
  =Sum(Filter(A:A,(A:A<>B:B))*(IsNumber(A:A)))
```

Comment: Sorry, you would need to adjust the formula to just be the data table. So whatever your column names are. The text will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use array formula:
type:
=sum(if(A2:A4>B2:B4,A2:A4,0))

then ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Good first answer, but SumProduct avoids having to hit CTL SHIFT Enter.